# SQL Server Mirroring and Azure Regions Connection Error

Tags: sql-server, azure, database-mirroring

I can't seem to get my SQL Server mirroring to work.  I keep getting a server can't be reached when I enable the mirroring part.

My virtual machines are in different regions.  I can connect to all SQL Servers (Primary, Mirror, Witness), and get all the way to the start mirroring but end up with a connect error.

Does the VM's in question that hold the SQL Server instance have to be in the same region, availability group, or affinity group?

Comment: Affinity groups have nothing to do with connectivity. And regions only come into play when dealing with egress and related costs + latency. That said: You should edit your question with more details about how you set up your VM's, as you've given no details, which means there's no answer - just guesses.

Comment: Added a little more information.  I stated them already but I guess it makes it clearer.